# how to get the global variable values after complete the function using javascript

Tags: javascript, onclick

i have declared global variable as "idle" (var a="idle"). I have also defined a button click handler. Inside that function i changed global variable values as a="pause". after that function is completed i want to get the current global value. How can i get it.

I have tried like these,In html file i have button,button id is a "pause".

```
<script>
var a="idle";
pause.onclick = function(){a = "pause"; }
console.log(a);
if(a=="pause")
alert("mani");
</script>
```

Comment: `pause.onclick = function(){a = "pause"; console.log(a);}` <- you have to check it when the click happens, not on the next line in your code.

Comment: SInce it's global, 'a' is available everywhere. But from the code shown, you'll never alert 'mani', since 'a' only becomes 'pause' after the click. So put the code `if (a === 'pause') alert('mani')` inside the onclick function, if that is what you're looking for.

Comment: no it doesnt work,@Shilly a is an global variable.i want ot change the variable value and perform some operation

Comment: i want the values tin next line.@adeneo

Answer (score 0):

Your code runs to the end before the button has been clicked, meaning that still `a != "pause"`. The easiest would be to add the alert within the button's `onclick` aswell. Note that you can also run any code other than alert in the `onclick` callback.

```html
<html>
<button id="pause">Pause</button>
<script>
var a="idle";
document.getElementById("pause").onclick = function(){
  a = "pause";
  alert("mani");
  afterwards();
};
function afterwards() {
  //code goes here, e.g.
  console.log("Afterwards: " + a);
}
console.log("Immediately: " + a);
</script>
</html>
```

The alternative is your own message-pump-like code which I would not suggest unless you got good reasons:

```html
<html>
<button id="pause">Pause</button>
<script>
var a="idle";
var alerted = false;
document.getElementById("pause").onclick = function(){ a = "pause"; }
console.log(a);
setInterval(() => { if (a == "pause" && !alerted) { alert("mani"); alerted = true; }}, 100);
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Immediately: function a(){
var a;
        a= "pause";
        return a;
                } I'm having these data in console

Comment: Changed code example. Note that javascript is in normal circumstances single-threaded and intended not to block but be event driven. I am not exactly sure what you want.

Comment: mode has been changed now but i want to check if(a== "pause"){//-----} how to move these check

Comment: Your code `if (a == "pause") { //... }` has to run at some point in time. I do not understand when you want to run it. I suggested doing whatever you want to do when `a == "pause"` after you set `a` to the according value, which appears to not be your intention.